# Inconveniente con selección de registros por medio de Combobox y muestreo en Celdas Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

Tengo el siguiente combobox como se señala con el numero 1, en la figura 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de procedencia de ese combobox es el siguiente:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim FILA, FINAL, I As Long
Dim LISTA As String

FILA = Hoja1.Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
FINAL = FILA - 1

For I = 2 To FINAL
  LISTA = Hoja1.Cells(I, 18)
  Hoja1.Cbo.AddItem (LISTA)
Next I

‘Teniendo en cuenta que Cbo es el combobox
End Sub
```

El anterior código me permite cargar con datos el combobox (Cbo)
Como vemos en la Figura 2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se necesita es que al seleccionar un país del combobox me muestre los datos en las siguientes celdas, como se ve señalado con el numero 1, en la figura 3:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero desafortunadamente no me lo cambia, me muestra el siguiente error cuando el nombre de un país es de una sola palabra, como cuando selecciono Surinam ver la Figura 4:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando selecciono nombre nombre de país compuesto, como por ejemplo “Trinidad y Tobago”, me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
 Private Sub Cbo_Change()
    Call conexion  'Llamamos el módulo Conexión
    If varcon.State = 1 Then
      'Generamos un comando, definiendo la variable command
      Dim command3 As New ADODB.command
       command3.ActiveConnection = varcon
       MsgBox Me.Cbo.Value
       command3.CommandText = "select * from infopaises where Pais= " & Me.Cbo.Value
    
       command3.CommandType = adCmdText
       command3.Execute
       Dim cr3 As ADODB.Recordset   
       Set cr3 = command3.Execute
       If cr3.EOF = False Then
        
         Do While Not cr3.EOF
         Dim col As Integer
         col = 10
         Hoja1.Cells(5, col) = cr3("IdPais")
         Hoja1.Cells(6, col) = cr3("Pais")
           Hoja1.Cells(7, col) = cr3("Extensión")
         Hoja1.Cells(8, col) = cr3("Habitantes")
         cr3.MoveNext
         Loop
    
      Else
      MsgBox "El conjunto de registros esta vacio"
      varcon.Close   'OJOOO Si cerramos esta variable nos va amostrar error
      Set varcon = Nothing 'OJOOO Si cerramos esta variable nos va amostrar error
    End If
    End If
    End Sub
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar

Comment: Hola, no he revisado todo pero en la cadena SQL te están faltando los apóstrofos que deben rodear a un valor cuando es del tipo texto:  "select * from infopaises where Pais= '" & Me.Cbo.Value  "'"

Comment: Respuesta acertada Sr Abraham.

Answer (score 2):

No respondiste el comentario, pero dejo el detalle para que a otros también les sirva por si tienen el mismo dilema.

Cuando se hace las consultas a base de datos, como la de este caso, si de texto se trata se debe encerrar entre apóstrofos del siguiente modo:

```
"select * from infopaises where Pais= '" & Me.Cbo.Value "'"
```

Saludos